# SQL DateTime Summation

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, time, sum

I have like this data:

[image]

I want to sum TIME_Column hours in specific year.

Summation of output for 2019 should be 12.5

Summation of output for 2020 should be 14.0

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: @D-Shih Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) isn't your (R)DBMS, @GürkanÖzdem , it's your IDE-like environment. SQL Server is your RDBMS. Answering SSMS is like answering "Microsoft Excel" when asked what operating system you are using; it gives us a likely candidate but it's not actually the correct answer.

Comment: Your "Time Column" looks wrong; why does it it have the date `1899-12-30` if it's a **time**?

Comment: @Larnu Thats the given data from machine we only interested in hours.

Comment: That doesn't answer why it has a date, @GürkanÖzdem . If it's meant to be a time, why is it not a `time`?

Comment: This is not my decision this data is a view. You should not stuck with that data type @Larnu

Comment: @GürkanÖzdem _this data is a view_ Then change the view to use the correct datatype. That is a trivial thing to do and will prevent future misunderstanding. For this goal, it might be rather pointless but someone at a future date might think that date portion is either significant or useful.

Comment: @Larnu - if we're going down the full pedantry route, why suggest storing something that appears to be a duration as a time?

Comment: With names like `Date_Column` and `Time_Column` that suggests more point in time that duration, @BenThul . The fact the OP wants to sum the values muddies that; add the fact that they have a date in 1899 and even more so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `DATEPART` to get hours & minute numbers from your `TIME_Column`, the minute numbers might need division by 60, then do `SUM` aggregate.

```
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, DATE_Column),SUM(DATEPART(HOUR, TIME_Column) + DATEPART(MINUTE, TIME_Column)/60.0)
FROM T
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, DATE_Column)
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c15204cb620c442459afcd8608b3fc07)

**NOTE**

I would combine `TIME_Column` & `DATE_Column` to one column, there might no reason need to spite datetime to two column I think.